# How do I find the next widget in a given direction in GTK+?

Tags: gtk, direction

I want to find out which widget is in a given direction in GTK+, i.e. doing what the "move-focus" signal does, but without actually changing the focus. What I have in mind is a function that takes a GtkWidget * and a GtkDirectionType and returns the GtkWidget in the given direction (if any).

What I want this for is to ultimately enumerate the widgets inside a specific GtkFrame in my UI definition, in order from left to right. I.e. basically create a list of widgets from leftmost to rightmost, inside my GtkFrame (or in the general case, inside any container).

I've tried to search the GTK documentation but haven't found anything that doesn't also change focus.

Answer (score 1):

Failing any other approach, the way I'm going forward with is to copy a selected set of static functions from the library implementation of GtkContainer and put them in a file in my own application, modifying them to suit my needs.

More specifically, the function gtk_container_focus_sort_left_right() and any local functions that it depends on. This includes the GCompareFunc left_right_compare() and get_allocation_coords().

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the directions you care about are "Forward" and "Backward", it sounds like you want to use [`gtk_container_get_focus_chain()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-get-focus-chain) on the frame: it does pretty much what it says on the tin: you get a list of widgets in order of focus when tabbing.

Comment: Actually, it's not the tab order I'm looking for, but rather the widgets that are reached by sending GTK_DIR_UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT as the argument to the "move-focus" signal. ("move-signal" can also take GTK_DIR_TAB_FORWARD/BACKWARD which shifts focus in tab order).

Comment: Besides, gtk_container_get_focus_chain() only returns the focus chain if explicitly set (with gtk_container_set_focus_chain() I assume, although I haven't tried it). It does not seem to return the default focus chain automatically computed by GTK+.

Comment: That last assumption is incorrect: focus chain should be calculated if one hasn't been set.

Comment: Calling gtk_container_get_focus_chain() without having called gtk_container_set_focus_chain() returns false, and the GList **focusable_widgets parameter is set to NULL at least in the implementation I have at hand here. I suspect that when actually moving focus a focus chain is somehow used, but at least gtk_container_get_focus_chain() doesn't access it.